# Определить самый нижний элемент на странице jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброй ночи. Не получается построить скрипт, который определят элемент с самым большим offset().top

НА странице есть несколько элементов с классом "block_act"
Я использую такую конструкцию, чтобы определить их все:

```
jQuery('.green_zone .block_act').each(function (index) { 
  console.log('OffsetTop: ' + jQuery(this).offset().top);
});
```

Но не знаю, как определить блок с Самым бОльшим оффсетом из них

Answer (score 4):

```js
var $lowestBlock,
    $blocks = jQuery('.green_zone .block_act'),
    blocksLength = $blocks.length,
    maxOffset = 0;

$blocks.each(function () {
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  var offset = $this.offset().top;
  
  if(offset > maxOffset) {
    maxOffset = offset;
    $lowestBlock = $this;
  }
});

$lowestBlock.css({ borderColor: 'green' });
```

```css
.green_zone {
  position: relative;
}

.block_act {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block_act--needly {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="green_zone">
  <div class="block_act"></div>
  <div class="block_act"></div>
  <div class="block_act"></div>
  <div class="block_act block_act--needly"></div>
  <div class="block_act"></div>
  <div class="block_act"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично! Благодарю, правда я немного под себя переписал ;)

Comment: @berTalino - это делать разрешается

Comment: @berTalino, подрихтовать под свою инфраструктуру - это норм )

Comment: Немного [компактней вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/vfeuLdkr/)

Comment: @Deonis, предпочитай давать ответ в соответствии с тем синтаксисом который в вопросе, так как не все используют babel. Можно ещё сократить.